# Possible to show "nearby" campaigns on lead/contact by geo?

Tags: geolocation

My goal is to show a list of related campaigns on a lead/contact profile that are "nearby" to the person based on their postal code. Ideally, I would add a custom field to the campaign object that would house a postal code and then if the campaign is active and within a set distance, it would appear on the lead/contact profile.

Is this possible? Any ideas where to start?

Comment: Have you looked into 'GeoLocation" custom fields?

Comment: Native geocoding was supposed to come w spring but got pushed back to pilot at the very last minute.  I got into the pilot and wrote up a post about using a custom field and calculating location against it.  Instead of a zip code if you used a lat/long you could do a cross object formula on campaign member. See my post for some details http://goravseth.com/geocode-all-the-records

Comment: @gorav that looks very close to what I'm looking for, but I think your last point is the deathblow for what I'm trying to do. I'd really like to say "show all leads/contacts within X distance of X location" and save that as a report and share it, but it doesn't sound like it's possible. And this kind of report would be cloned a lot, with the X location changing, so I don't think it'd work without that flexibility?

Comment: @matt correct at present only could share list view, or use formula fields to hard code distance to specific locations.  Dynamic not really feasible other than my per user approach.

Comment: One note, with the per user approach you could add to campaign and share the campaign.   Hopefully full support in reports would come soon

Comment: Sorry for the comment spam.  Rereading this, IF you use lat/long on campaign instead of zip, then create a formula on campaign member to show distance to that lat/long, the report could be shared, as the location is being calculated against the field on the campaign.

Comment: @gorav but that would require that I essentially add everyone in the DB to each campaign in order to compare them, right?

Comment: Ahh yes sorry that is right.  You would have to add everyone...not practical for most cases.